# one section of website is not fitting in the layout

Tags: html, css

I can't  seem to get my 4th section to fall into line with the other sections.
Any help or clues would be greatly appreciated. I am at a loss as to what is wrong, I keep messing around with the chrome devolper tool trying to luck into a solution.

http://landonsimmons.altervista.org/School/assign7/assign7.html

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utc-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <img src="img/logo.png" />
                <span>Computer Science Department</span>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Programs</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="proglist.html">Program List</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <section id="left">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a>Computer Programming</a>
                        <a>Computer Specialist</a>
                    </li><br>
                    <li>
                        <a>Information Technology Analysis</a>
                    </li><br>
                    <li>
                        <a>Information Technology Management</a>
                    </li><br>

                <li>
                    <a>Network System Developer</a>
                </li><br>

                <li>
                    <a>Web Development Specialist</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section id="middle">
            <h1 id="hist">History of College</h1>
            <p id="first">
            </p>
            <p>
            </p>
            <h1 id="comp">About Computer Science</h1>
            <p>
            <img id="img" src="img/Capture3.PNG" />
                While the computing field is one of the fastest growing segments of industry, 
                it is also one of the fastest changing areas technologically. Computing professionals
                education does not stop with the college degree, but continues with seminars, conferences, and advanced courses and training.
                In computer theory and applications, new ideas are developed every day. 
                Success requires an ongoing commitment to learning to maintain knowledge, skills and career opportunities.
            </p>

        </section>
        <section id="right">
            <h1 id="gain">Gainful Employment Information</h1>
            <p> 
                The U.S. Department of Education requires colleges to disclose a variety of information for any financial 
                aid eligible program that <q>prepares students for gainful employment in a recognized occupation.</q> The information provided 
                here describes the graduation rates, the median debt of students who 
                completed the program and other important information regarding gainful employment for the latest completed academic year (as of July 1).
            </p>
            <br>
            <p style="font-size: 13px">&mdash; US Labor Department</p>
        </section>
        <section id="bot">
            <video height=260 width=323 >       
                <source src="vid/a1.mp4"/>
            </video>
        </section>

        <footer>
            <address> 

            </address>
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
/***********************************************
font
***********************************************/

pre {
    font-family: serif;
}

#first::first-letter {
    font-size: 45px;
}

#big b {
    letter-spacing: 4px; 
    font-family: serif; 
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 180px
}

#middle p {
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

#right p {
     margin:  16px 30px;
}

h1 {
    padding: 5px 40px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

footer address {
        color: green;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bolder;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: sans-serif;
}

/***********************************************
page setup
***********************************************/

body {
    background-image: url(../img/parch.jpg);
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 25px 8px 0 8px;
}

#left {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#middle {
    width: 40%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;

}

video {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#bot {
    float: right;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    width: 38%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: sub;
}

#right {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    width: 38%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

#small {
    width: 18%;
    text-align: center; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#big a {
    letter-spacing: 8px;
}

#big {
    width: 75%;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 25px;
}



#img {
    max-height: 90px;
    max-width: 140px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float: right;
}



/***********************************************
color scheme
***********************************************/

#comp {
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;

    color: #872E3F;
}

#gain {
    background-color: #B28570;
    text-align: center;
}

#hist {
    background-color: black;
    color: #872E3F;
    text-align: center;
}

#right {
    background-color: #FFC1A2;
}


/***********************************************
Header
***********************************************/

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #000;
}


header span {
    color: #D2E1FF;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}

/***********************************************
nav + list
***********************************************/

#left ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

#left ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#small ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

#small ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;    
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 15px 0 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #0000FC;
} 

nav ul li {
    display: inline;    

}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: red;
}

#small ul li a:hover,
#left ul li a:hover {
    color: #ff6666;
    outline: 1px double black;
}

/***********************************************
footer
***********************************************/

footer {
    clear: right;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... is your fourth section the one called bot? If so, is it supposed to be to the right of right?

Comment: yes the 4th section is bot, it's supposed to be right under the right section, but instead there is that giant gap to top and right of it.

Comment: alright, I'll see what I can do about that when I get back from dinner.

Comment: thank you good sir!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two changes you will have to made

Add `float:left;` to `#middle` and change `clear:right` to `clear:both` for footer css.

```
    footer  { clear:both; }
    #middle {float:left;width: 40%;border-right: 1px solid black;border-left: 1px solid black;display: inline-block;}
```

Working [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/creativemind1/pen/QEGdpo)

Comment: Thank you so much I have been trying to fix this for a few hours now! I really appreciate the help! It's up and running now! Thank you again!

Comment: Darn, ya beat me to it. Sometimes I wish I wasn't bound to human needs such as eating, or breathing.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this :

- put `right` and `bot` section in a new div
- the new div should have the `right` styles as a class style = `.right` so you can keep the `#right` section style
- take out borders, floats, and  `#right` and `#bot`

Look at the result there :

http://lespointscom.com/a/misc/demo/2016_06_21/question_2/assign7.html

**changed HTML**

```
    <div class="right">
        <section id="right">
            <h1 id="gain">Gainful Employment Information</h1>
            <p> 
                The U.S. Department of Education requires colleges to disclose a variety of information for any financial 
                aid eligible program that <q>prepares students for gainful employment in a recognized occupation.</q> The information provided 
                here describes the graduation rates, the median debt of students who 
                completed the program and other important information regarding gainful employment for the latest completed academic year (as of July 1).
            </p>
            <br>
            <p style="font-size: 13px">— US Labor Department</p>
        </section>

        <section id="bot">
            <video height="260" width="323">        
                <source src="http://landonsimmons.altervista.org/School/assign7/vid/a1.mp4">
            </video>
        </section>
    </div>
```

**changed CSS**

```
#bot {
/*float: right;
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
width: 38%;*/
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: sub;
}

#right {
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    width: 38%;*/
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: right;*/
}
```